# OpenGl: GLSurfaceView.Renderer or GLSurfaceView?

Tags: android, opengl-es, surfaceview, renderer, glsurfaceview

What are the differences between those two, and also, which is better?

Answer (score 2):

These are two different things: GLSurfaceView is a View to draw your objects on, and GLSurfaceView.Renderer is an interface, whose methods should be overridden to draw your objects. You can a look at [this](http://blog.jayway.com/2009/12/03/opengl-es-tutorial-for-android-part-i/) set of tutorials to get started with OpenGL in Android. Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

short version:

GLSurfaceView owns GLSurfaceView.Render.

long version:

GLSurfaceView extends SurfaceView and additionally owns a render thread and a render object set by the client. The render thread keeps running , continuously or on-demand, and delegates to the render object to draw frame using OpenGL API. For both SurfaceView and GLSurfaceView, rendering is performing in a separate thread other than main thread. The difference is with SurfaceView the rendering thread is created by client while with GLSurfaceView it is created by the system. What's more, GLSurfaceView will internally handle the synchronization between main thread and rendering thread.

http://pierrchen.blogspot.jp/2014/04/android-ui-internal-glsurfaceview.html